# Replace the value with the previous occurrence of acronym using python regular expression module

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, python-re

I need to add the previous word to -number which had occurred before -number of the sentence. Please go through the input string and expected output string for more clarification. I have tried the `.replace`, `.sub` methods of regex with static way which is kind of manipulated output.

**Input String:**

> The acnes stimulated the mRNA expression of interleukin (IL)-1, -8, LL-37, MMP-1, -2, -3, -9, and -13 in keratinocytes.

**Expected Output String:**

> The acnes stimulated the mRNA expression of interleukin (IL)-1, interleukin (IL)-8, LL-37, MMP-1, MMP-2, MMP-3, MMP-9, and MMP-13 in keratinocytes.

**Code:**

```py
import re
string_a = "The acnes stimulated the mRNA expression of interleukin (IL)-1, -8, LL-37, MMP-1, -2, -3, -9, and -13 in keratinocytes."
regex1 = re.findall(r"[a-z]+\s+\(+[A-Z]+\)+-\d+\,\s+-\d\,+", string_a)
regex2 = re.findall(r"[A-Z]+-\d+\,\s+-\d\,\s+-\d\,\s+-\d\,\s+[a-z]+\s+-\d+", string_a)
```

Comment: could you make your example string a little shorter?

Comment: @PatrickParker I have made it shorter now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
string_a = "The acnes stimulated the mRNA expression of interleukin (IL)-1, -8, LL-37, MMP-1, -2, -3, -9, and -13 in keratinocytes."
pattern = re.compile(r"\b([A-Za-z]+\s*\([A-Z]+\)|[A-Z]+)(\s*-\d+(?:,\s*-\d+)*)(?:,\s*and\s+(-\d+))?")
print( pattern.sub(lambda x: x.group(1) + f', {x.group(1)}'.join(map(str.strip, x.group(2).strip().split(','))) + (f', and {x.group(1)}{x.group(3)}' if x.group(3) else ''), string_a) )
# => The acnes stimulated the mRNA expression of interleukin (IL)-1, interleukin (IL)-8, LL-37, MMP-1, MMP-2, MMP-3, MMP-9, and MMP-13 in keratinocytes.
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/B5L8xo) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mgwcJz/2).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `([A-Za-z]+\s*\([A-Z]+\)|[A-Z]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more ASCII letters, then zero or more whitespaces, `(`, one or more uppercase ASCII letters, and a `)`, *OR* one or more uppercase ASCII letters
- `(\s*-\d+(?:,\s*-\d+)*)` - Capturing group 2: zero or more whitespaces, `-`, one or more digits, and then zero or more sequences of a comma, zero or more whitespaces, `-` and one or more digits
- `(?:,\s*and\s+(-\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group: a comma, zero or more whitespaces, `and`, one or more whitespaces, then a Capturing group 3: `-`, one or more digits.

The Group 1 value is prepended to all Group 2 comma-separated numbers inside a lambda used as a replacement argument.

If Group 3 matched, `and`+space+concatenated Group 1 and Group 3 values are appended.

Comment: @SachinSinkar I have seen it, but it is not clear to me what the rules are here.